# How to solve this equation used to calculate vertical and horizontal field of view?

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following equation which I don't know how to solve, I'm not that good at math and especially not with trigonometry. Any help would be very welcome and appreciated:

I'm trying to find $V$.

Following is known:
$h=500$
$w = 750$

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All your equations are equivalent. All three of them contain the same information about $V$.

If you only know $h$ and $w$, and don't know what $H$ is, then you can't find $V$. If you *do* know $H$, then you can find $V$ from the last equation.

Comment: Isn't it possible to solve this like so? :
since h = tan(V/2) you could take the inv tan of h x 2 ?

Comment: @MircoProgram but you don't know that $h=\tan(V/2)$, and it probably isn't true. For instance, you have that $\frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{6}$, but certainly $3\neq 6$.